# how do you pick certain lines from a log file with R

Tags: r, regex

there is a log file like this and it has many entries in them:

```
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3

Report Job information
Job ID : 12345
Job name : Background Execution
Job priority : 5
Job group : normal
Report group : General
Job description : Brief
User : user01
Report : General101
Modified user : 12
Modified date : 2016-09-16 15:18:52.08
Report mode : Simple

2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3

Report Job information
Job ID : 12367
Job name : Background Execution
Job priority : 5
Job group : normal
Report group : General1
Job description : Brief
User : user01
Report : General101
Modified user : 12
Modified date : 2016-09-16 15:45:52.08
Report mode : Simple
```

I need to be able to extract this part from the log and put in a data frame format. The log will have many entries like this, every time the script see this set up entries in the log, it should append to the data frame.

```
    Report Job information
    Job ID : 12367
    Job name : Background Execution
    Job priority : 5
    Job group : normal
    Report group : General1
    Job description : Brief
    User : user01
    Report : General101
    Modified user : 12
    Modified date : 2016-09-16 15:45:52.08
    Report mode : Simple
```

I've tried this:

```
  i<-c("app.log")
    xx <- readLines(i)
    ii <- 10 + grep("Report Job information",xx, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_count <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(xx[ii]," ")[[2]])
```

Any ideas how could do this?

Given this data:

```
Job ID : 12345
Job name : Background Execution
Job priority : 5
Job group : normal
Report group : General
Job description : Brief
User : user01
Report : General101
Modified user : 12
Modified date : 2016-09-16 15:18:52.08
Report mode : Simple


Each set of entry need to be one row. For example:
title=Report Job information,jobid=12345, JobName=Background Execution, job priority=5,jobgroup=normal, reportgroup=General,ModifiedDate=2016-09-16 15:18:52.08 etc
```

Comment: Whats about `i <- grep("Report Job information", xx); cbind(sapply(i, function(x, y) y[c(x:(x+11))], xx))`?

Comment: @Jimbou, thanks for your answer, each set of entry need to be one row,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the data, read in (note, using `dplyr`/`magrittr` pipe):

```
inData <-
"2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3

Report Job information
Job ID : 12345
Job name : Background Execution
Job priority : 5
Job group : normal
Report group : General
Job description : Brief
User : user01
Report : General101
Modified user : 12
Modified date : 2016-09-16 15:18:52.08
Report mode : Simple

2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3
2016-09-16 15:18:52,555 DEBUG Thread-3

Report Job information
Job ID : 12367
Job name : Background Execution
Job priority : 5
Job group : normal
Report group : General1
Job description : Brief
User : user01
Report : General101
Modified user : 12
Modified date : 2016-09-16 15:45:52.08
Report mode : Simple" %>%
  strsplit("\\n") %>%
  unlist
```

I think that the easiest is to first find all of the starting positions. Here, I assume that "Report Job Information" is at the top of each report (but that it does not need to be included in the data.frame, so I start one after it).

```
reportStarts <-
  grep("Report Job information", inData) + 1
```

Next, I find where the reports end. Not knowing more about the structure, I am assuming that "Report mode" is the last thing reported. If, instead, it is a set number of lines, or some other break indicator, you may need to modify this step.

```
reportStops <-
  grep("Report mode", inData)
```

Next, I loop through each of the reports (using `idx` to indicate which report I am working on). the approach first limits to the lines in this report, then splits each by " : " which appears to be the field indicator, and uses the part before the " : " to name the output (I use paste as a defense in case the value also includes a " : "). Finally, I stitch each into a data.frame, then bind the rows with `bind_rows` to ensure that it appropriately handles any extra columns that may be present in some reports.

```
lapply(1:length(reportStarts), function(idx){

  inData[reportStarts[idx]:reportStops[idx]] %>%
    strsplit(" : ") %>%
    sapply(function(thisField){
      setNames(paste(thisField[-1]
                     , collapse = " : ")
               , thisField[1])
    }) %>%
    rbind %>%
    data.frame()

}) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Outputs this `data.frame`:

```
  Job.ID             Job.name Job.priority Job.group Report.group Job.description   User     Report Modified.user          Modified.date Report.mode
1  12345 Background Execution            5    normal      General           Brief user01 General101            12 2016-09-16 15:18:52.08      Simple
2  12367 Background Execution            5    normal     General1           Brief user01 General101            12 2016-09-16 15:45:52.08      Simple
```

Comment: I get this error: Variables not shown: Job.description (chr), User (chr), Report (chr), Modified.user (chr),
  Modified.date (chr), Report.mode (chr)

Comment: since I'll be reading from a directory many files, I need to reach file in for loop like this: for (i in logs){
  xx <- readLines(i)
  
  reportStarts <-
    grep("Report Job information", xx) + 1

Comment: That is not an error. It appears that you have the class `tbl_df` attached to your output, which comes with some pretty printing features (limits columns to what fits on the screen and rows to a reasonable length). The whole data.frame s still there. That is telling you that there are more variables than can fit on the screen. If you want those to print, you can use `print(dataFrameName, width = Inf)"

Comment: If you are reading from many files, you can just drop all of what I have (ID of start/stop and the `lapply` loop) inside another loop. If using `for`, just save each output (from `lapply`) to an element in a list, then use `bind_rows` on the list of data.frames. Alternatively, if you use `lapply` instead of for, you can just pass the output of your whole loop straight to `bind_rows`, much like I did here.

Comment: one quick question. If any of the fields empty, how do I force NA? If Job.description   is empty in the file, how can I put NA?

Comment: It depends on what "empty" means in your log files. If the line is missing altogether, the code should work correctly. If the line lacks a space, it will put an NA, but generate an additional column. If the line has a space after the colon, then nothing, it currently returns a blank (`""`) which may be reflective of the entered value. If you want to convert all blanks to `NA` you can pipe the output through `mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == "", NA, as.character(.))), everything())`.

Comment: in some files, I do see this field empty like this: Job description : , and it is causing script the fail. I tried mutate_each function but I get this error: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: xx[reportStarts[idx]:reportStops[idx]] %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == "", NA, as.character(.))), everything()) %>%
            strsplit(" : ") %>%

Comment: The `mutate_each` call would go *after* the `bind_rows`. How is it failing when you do not use `mutate_each`?

Comment: I did that, still getting this error:  Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: @Mike Peterson, I think I found the problem. Sometimes, I do see these between start and stop: Job description : 32307,61112,72216,70150
CLEARER - 93387, there is an extra line called CLEARER, how I remove this line?

Comment: That would cause a problem. Likely use something like `grep("CLEARER", inData, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE` (search for "CLEARER", return all entries that do not match) *before* search for start and stop sites. Alternatively, you could invert the strategy to only return matches that you *want* to keep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125415/discussion-between-user1471980-and-mark-peterson).

Comment: I see some other issues. Would you be able to chat?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
library(stringr)

foo <- function(x, y){
  tmp <- y[c(x:(x+11))] # extract
  tmp <- str_split(tmp, ": ") # split and optimize
  unlist(lapply(tmp, tail, 1)) # unlist and output last element
  }

data.frame(t(cbind(sapply(i, foo, xx))))
                      X1    X2                   X3 X4     X5       X6    X7     X8         X9 X10
1 Report Job information 12345 Background Execution  5 normal  General Brief user01 General101  12
2 Report Job information 12367 Background Execution  5 normal General1 Brief user01 General101  12
                     X11    X12
1 2016-09-16 15:18:52.08 Simple
2 2016-09-16 15:45:52.08 Simple
```